# MacOS: Dropdowns in Finder disappear

Tags: macos, finder

I have the problem, that since a few days, i am not able to select from dropdown menus in finder anymore.
They drop down but as soon as i lower my mouse they automaticaly fade away. Even if i go fast and try to click them while its still there, it won't select a new folder.
This happens in Finder and in other Applications (Save As..)

Please see the video attached. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhdyfxvaotge7tj/Dropdown-Problem.mov?dl=0

Macbook Pro 16" 2019 i9 32gb RAM, MacOS Monterey 12.0.1

Any ideas on how to fix this? I already did SMC and PRAM resets without any changes to this problem.

Comment: I can see the issue - but it doesn't look like it's "not selecting" it looks like its "selecting the first one", the menu blinks which implies "selection". Try this test, see if there's a noticeable difference. It's a timing test. 1. click-hold, drag, let go. 2. Click let go [really short tap], wait 2s, slide cursor to desired line, click again. The Mac has 2 behaviours for this [same with ordinary app menus] If one works but the other doesn't, it *might* give us a hint [or at least a workaround].

Comment: Tried your tests out today. still no chance to select anything else than the first column. I have to add, that the problem magically appears and disappears, even without restarting the computer or any apps. It just behaves like that, and a few hours later, everything works as normally expected.

Comment: I'd have suspected a dodgy mouse button, but we've probably eliminated that. idk what else to suggest except the usual troubleshooting avenues - new admin account, safe boot etc - to see if it's a software conflict.

Comment: Somehow, the Click-and-drag test that you mentioned worked now. So if the problem is there at the moment, clicking and draging seems to work most of the times, when single click and then moving the mouse wont work.

Comment: I'd try a different mouse, just to eliminate that as a cause.

Comment: I just tried the internal trackpad and a MX Master connected via Bluetooth. Same problem. I might try going into safe boot, or even doing a clean install. Somehow the system has a lot of these minor bugs and hangups…